# PL/SQL split full address in street number and street name

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

I need help writing a PL/SQL script.
I want to split a column containing addresses in 2 other columns for street numbers and street names.

Those are french addresses and must be formatted this way :

```
Address
--------------------
10 BIS RUE DE LA REPUBLIQUE
15 RUE DU 18 DECEMBRE
CC LES 4 TEMPS
5 TER IMPASSE DE LA VIGNE
7 QUATER AV CHARLES DE GAULLE

Number  |Street
--------------------
10B     |RUE DE LA REPUBLIQUE
15      |RUE DU 18 DECEMBRE
        |CC LES 4 TEMPS
5T      |IMPASSE DE LA VIGNE
7Q      |AV CHARLES DE GAULLE
```

1) When address starts with a number, this number is used for Number column. If address contains a number, not at the beginning, it goes in the Street column.

2) If street number is followed by "BIS", "TER", "QUATER" or "QUINQUIES", street number is followed by "B", "T", "Q" or "C".

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Andy's right, but good chance someone will write it for him anyway

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written. It is not, however, a "do my homework for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting; or, the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and what tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. For me it looks cumbersome, but works. I guess it could be written in more optimal way.

```
  WITH t(address) AS
    (SELECT '10 BIS RUE DE LA REPUBLIQUE'
     FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT '15 RUE DU 18 DECEMBRE'
     FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT 'CC LES 4 TEMPS'
     FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT '5 TER IMPASSE DE LA VIGNE'
     FROM dual
     UNION ALL SELECT '7 QUATER AV CHARLES DE GAULLE'
     FROM dual)
SELECT address ,
       CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(address, '^[0-9]+\s+(BIS|TER|QUATER|QUINQUIES)') THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(address,'^[0-9]+\s+.'),'\s+')
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(address, '^[0-9]+') THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(address,'^[0-9]+')
       END num ,
       CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(address, '^[0-9]+\s+(BIS|TER|QUATER|QUINQUIES)?') THEN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(address, '^[0-9]+\s+(BIS|TER|QUATER|QUINQUIES)?'))
           ELSE address
       END street
FROM t ;
```